# Adding multiple text-shadow rules with javascript on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply this types of css properties to the given element when clicking on a button:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #b77e42,
             2px 2px 0 #b77e42,
             3px 3px 0 #b77e42,
             4px 4px 0 #b77e42;
```

but I end up with these rules instead:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #b77e42;
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7MWh/)

Comment: Are you trying to apply multiple shadows? Your code seems to apply a single shadow and increment the x/y on click.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, that is correct. I want it to have the original one, then another one incremented by 1 added to it.

Comment: You want it to increment each time you click the button, or one click applies all 4 styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your commas. Each rule needs to be divided by a comma. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/PZpY8/)**

```
function addShadow(element) {

  var appliedStyle = i + 'px ' + i + 'px ' + '0 #b77e42';

  var current = element.style.textShadow;

  if (current) {
    //if there's already a style, add a comma before adding new
    current+= ',';
  }

  element.style.textShadow= current+appliedStyle;

  i++;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't even think of testing the property first.